# Why the user interface for superuser.com has changed

Tags: support, user-interface

Last night (26-Feb-2016), I used the site (superuser.com) and this morning I see that the complete user interface part has changed.
I liked the old one. Why this change?
Was this discussed in the community? Did I miss something?

The graph showing the `reputations` is also gone.
[[image]

**Additional note: This is happened only in Microsoft Edge browser. My Chrome has the old excellent interface**

**Added the userstring**
[image]

Comment: I was not allowed to post the question till I added the `bug` tag. Why is that?

Comment: It looks the same to me, have you installed any script or ad blockers? Unless there's some testing going on and you're getting a different interface for some reason...

Comment: That's the mobile view.  Are you on a desktop or mobile browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing there is the mobile view.

If you scroll down to the very bottom of the page you will see a link that says "full site" which will set a cookie in your browser to give you the desktop version of the site:

[image]

As to *why* your browser suddenly switched to that version I'm not sure.  Are you able to post your useragent string?  You can get it from http://www.useragentstring.com/

Comment: I don't know what triggered the switch to mobile then, my copy of Edge has the same userstring and didn't go to the mobile site. Maybe Stack is using some other mechanism that falsely identified you as a mobile user. At the very least you have a way to change it. Alternatively if you actually want the mobile version then there is a "mobile" link at the bottom of every page next to the contact us link

Comment: Thanks for the update. My Windows 10 is infected with malware. It opens random pop up tabs. That could also be the reason??

Comment: How would we know.  Remove the malware and find out.

Comment: [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)